# Do Mercurial bundle files support internal integrity checks?

Tags: mercurial

I am working on a project with developers around the globe and we are using mercurial for our source control solution. Currently, we communicate our change sets by creating bundles and posting to a mailing list. A disagreement has arisen about best practices, and we have not been able to find an answer in the mercurial documentation.

When creating a bundle, is there any sort of internal integrity check that occurs? Or should we be sending digests along with the change set to ensure file integrity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bundle contains exactly the same data as the data transferred by the wire protocol. Due to the way mercurial works, there's a [recursive hashing scheme](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/behind-the-scenes.html#id358156) going on, so every revision must be uncorrupted in order to be used.